# Check if a program is running on particular node or not

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have found this script to check if the program is running or not. but i do have multiple servers(it's a spark cluster) where my program might be running.

With this script i need to run shell script on the same node where my actual program is running. Then only i can find out the service.

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='myProgram'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running"
    echo "$SERVICE is not running!" | mail -s "$SERVICE down" root
fi
```

Can anyone help me to write a program to check if a process is running on any one of the servers that i listed? If not i need to give OS return code of non-zero.

It's like while shell script is running on server1 i need ssh to node2 and check if the program is running there are not.

Comment: We can help *you* write it. But not if you just give the requirements and ask for a full solution. Instead please ask a question that will help you progress your own code. What is the next step that you don't know how to do? What approaches have you considered and/or tried?

Comment: i would like to check if a program is running on particular server or not. how do i check that in a unix shell script.?

Answer (score 0):

This script will be a good starting point for your question.
You can run this script on one of your server with a user who can ssh
to other servers without passwd.
I suppose you know the role of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files.
I hope you will pick up some bash knowledge that necessary for this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE='myProgram'
nodes="nodeA nodeB nodeC nodeD"

rm -f err.log 2>/dev/null

for nd in $nodes ; do
  rm tmp_file 2>/dev/null
  ssh -o "NumberOfPasswordPrompts 0" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $nd \
      ps ax |grep -vw grep  >tmp_file 2>>error.log
  test -s tmp_file || { printf "$nd: SSH failed\n" |tee -a error.log; continue; }
  if (( `grep -cw "$SERVICE" tmp_file` > 0 ))
  then
      echo "$SERVICE service running on $nd, everything is fine"
  else
      echo "$SERVICE is not running on $nd"
      echo "$SERVICE is not running on $nd!" | mail -s "$SERVICE down on $nd" root
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nodejs and a package called SSH2shell it is possible to connect to multiple hosts, run different commands sequentially on each host (or the same commands on all hosts), create, run and remove bash scripts on the fly. The responses from each command is returned for each host either as they are run using `onCommandComplete` event or at the end of the session using `onEnd` event to process `sessionText`. On primary host disconnection the full text from all hosts is processed by the callback or primary host `onEnd` event. It is possible to add or remove commands based on the command run and any part of its response using onCommandComplete or onCommandProcessing events.

### Example:

```
//This array of commands checks if a script already exists, if so it
//will run it and then remove it.
//If not it will printf the bash script contents to a script file
//It will then make the script exicutable using sudo chmod
//The script is run then the script is deleted.
//If you don't want to delete the file remove the last rm command.

var bashScriptHandling = ["if [ ! -f myscript.sh ]; then printf '#!/bin/bash\n" +
    "SERVICE='myProgram'\n\n" +
    "if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null\n" +
    "then\n" +
    "    echo \"$SERVICE service running, everything is fine\"\n" +
    "else\n" +
    "    echo \"$SERVICE is not running\"\n" +
    "    echo \"$SERVICE is not running!\" | mail -s \"$SERVICE down\"\n" +
    "    root\n" +
    "fi'",
    "sudo chmod 700 myscript.sh",
    "./myscript.sh",
    "rm myscript.sh"]

//Multiple host connections can be made by adding host objects to
//host.hosts array of any host.
//In this case host1 is the primary host from which all other hosts
//are connected in a number of possible arrangements.
//Host1 runs a ssh command to connect to host2, the commands for that 
//host are run and then any hosts in its host.hosts array are connected
//to. Host2 connects to host3 and host3's commands are run. 
//Then each host connection is terminated storing host session text
//in host1's sessionText passed to the callback function or onEnd 
//event. Host3 handles its own sessionText using the onEnd event.

host3 = {
  //set the connection options here
  server:             {     
    host:         hostthree.com,
    port:         22,
    userName:     user3,
    password:     password3
  },
  //set commands here
  commands:       bashScriptHandling,
  //Host3 handling of its own sessionText using onEnd event
  onEnd:          funtion( sessionText, sshObj ){
      this.emit('msg', "Host 3 session text:-------------\n\n" +
          sessionText)
  }
}

host2 = {
  server:             {     
    host:         hosttwo.com,
    port:         22,
    userName:     user2,
    password:     password2
  },
  commands:       bashScriptHandling,
  hosts:          [host3]
}

host1 = {
  server:         {     
    host:         hostone.com,
    port:         22,
    userName:     user,
    password:     password1
  },
  commands:       ["msg:primary connection host"],
  hosts:          [host2]
}

var SSH2Shell = require ('ssh2shell');


var SSH = new SSH2Shell(host1),
    callback = function( sessionText ){
          console.log ( "-----Callback session text:\n" + sessionText);
          console.log ( "-----Callback end" );
      }

SSH.connect(callback)
```

This should give you a framework to structure a solution using SSH2shell.

See [SSH2shell on github](https://github.com/cmp-202/ssh2shell) for extensive readme help on all aspects of use with plenty of code examples.

See [test files for code examples](https://github.com/cmp-202/ssh2shell/tree/master/test) used for parts of my example.

Comment: Any host could use `host.commands = ["./myscript", "./myScriptTwo",......],` instead of `bashScriptHandling`.